# Why is my html file unable to find the UpdateSites method(Uncaught ReferenceError: UpdateSites is not defined)?

Tags: angular, html, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have set-up a simple drop-down menu this way:

> table.component.html

```
      <select class="form-control" onchange="UpdateSites(this.value)">
  <!-- //  console.log('FormControlChangeTest' + this.value)"> -->
      <option>France - Paris (Majunga)</option>
      <option>France - Paris (Opus)</option>  
</select>
```

> table.component.ts

```
export class TableComponent {
 private UpdateSites(siteName){
    console.log('SITE NAME IS'+ siteName)
  }
```

In the chrome console, I have this error:

> table:35 Uncaught ReferenceError: UpdateSites is not defined
>       at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (table:35)

I would like to know what am I doing wrong exactly. i.e: Why isn't the html file finding the UpdateSites method.
PS: Out of curiosity I placed the UpdateSites outside of the class component but in the same file. However this still didn't work.

Comment: because your method is private. You need to make your method public in order to access them in html template

Comment: @JoharZaman no they're still accessible even if they're private. I have changed it to public just to try it and it didn't work

Comment: I also have other private methods :

Comment: [getRowHeight]="getRowHeight"
this works perfectly!

Comment: try this: `(onChange)="UpdateSites($event.target.value)"

Comment: `$event.target.value` will give you selected value from dropdown

Comment: No I don't have a problem with retrieving the value. this.value works fine

Comment: but you cannot bind `onchange` event like you are doing. Try this: `<select class="form-control" (onChange)="UpdateSites(this.value)">`

Comment: (onchange)="UpdateSites($event.target.value)

Comment: public UpdateSites(siteName){
    console.log('SITE NAME IS'+ siteName)
  }

Comment: Thank you. The error has been removed. However, I do not see anything on the console log!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y7zyqc

**Code:**

```html
<select class="form-control" (change)="UpdateSites($event.target.value)">
  <!-- //  console.log('FormControlChangeTest' + this.value)"> -->
      <option>France - Paris (Majunga)</option>
      <option>France - Paris (Opus)</option>  
</select>
```

I just changed html to above snippet and it's working now. You can check in above example.

Comment: I just changed the url if it the value is undefined in the console try new url. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! You're a life save! If anyone is reading this: make sure to write change instead of onchange!